# JQPlot error in seaside pharo smalltalk

Tags: jquery, smalltalk, jqplot, pharo, seaside

I had used the following code and i am receiving the firefox firebug error.

Code:

```
(canvas anchor)
    id:(canvas nextId);
    onClick:  'alert("Thank you");';
    with:'help me'.
```

I could load the jqplot libraries in updateRoot SUCCESSFULLY as follows:

```
updateRoot: t1

super updateRoot: t1.


t1 javascript resourceUrl:'gemstone/scripts/dist/jquery.min.js'.
t1 javascript resourceUrl:'gemstone/scripts/dist/jquery.jqplot.min.js'.
t1 javascript resourceUrl:'gemstone/scripts/dist/plugins/jqplot.blockRenderer.min.js'.
t1 javascript resourceUrl:'gemstone/scripts/dist/plugins/jqplot.enhancedLegendRenderer.min.js'.
t1 javascript resourceUrl:'gemstone/scripts/dist/plugins/jqplot.bubbleRenderer.min.js'.

t1 javascript resourceUrl:'gemstone/scripts/dist/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js'.
t1 javascript resourceUrl:'gemstone/scripts/dist/plugins/jqplot.pieRenderer.min.js'.
t1 javascript resourceUrl:'gemstone/scripts/dist/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js'.
t1 javascript resourceUrl:'gemstone/scripts/dist/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js'.
t1 stylesheet resourceUrl:'gemstone/scripts/dist/jquery.jqplot.min.css'.**.
```

I am not getting any alert and  I am receiving the following javascript error in firebug in firefox.

**$("#id1").on is not a function**

Comment: Please show the part of code that is relevant to the error code. Maybe you are missing something?

Comment: I had written the code in the renderContentOn:html method. No extra code is written anywhere..:-(

Comment: So what is "#id1"? Also where the error is located? Usually FireBug points you to the script where the error was thrown.

Comment: Did you check the page source?

Comment: @Boro $("#id1").on is not a function
http://localhost:8080/Pitagora
Line 1..This is the error which is shown by the firebug

Comment: @SeanDeNigris the source code part says       <a id="id1">help meee </a>
<span title="Callback Time">0</span>/<span title="Render Time">0</span> ms</span></div><script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/$(function(){$("#id1").on("click",function(){alert("Thank you");});});/*]]>*/</script>

Comment: @Boro the source code part says <a id="id1">help meee </a> <span title="Callback Time">0</span>/<span title="Render Time">0</span> ms</span></div><script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[/$(function(){$("#id1").on("click",function()‌​{alert("Thank you");});});/]]>*/</script>

Comment: The code is unreadable in comments add an **EDIT** section in you question and then remove these comments.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the '**.' at the end of your #updateRoot: method and see what happens.

Check the rendered html in the body of the page for your root component.  It should be:

```
<a id="id1" onclick="alert("Thank you");">help me</a>
```

Nothing you've shown should change that.  If its not then you need to give more information.

Comment: I dont know why.. but the code had worked for me when i commented the first line "t1 javascript resourceUrl:'gemstone/scripts/dist/jquery.min.js"